# Split Artist - Title JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, split, separator

I have the following script:

```
const Parser = require('../src');

const radioStation = new Parser('http://stream.com/live_32.aac');

radioStation.on('metadata', function(metadata) {
    console.log([metadata.StreamTitle]);
});
```

The output on the console is:

```
Artist - Title
```

I want to split the Artist and Title.

I found something like:

```
str.split(separator)
```

But it's not working correct.

Does any one have a solution?

Comment: `I want to split the Artist and Title.` what for ? What output do you expect ?

Comment: I want to split it, For example: Console.log output: Artist and Console.log Title.

Comment: you want to store each value to 2 different variables ?

Comment: Yes! That's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were write, [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) creates from your string an array of 2 elements : `["Artist "," Title"]`.

As you can see there are whitespaces. [trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) removes those whitespaces (`map` is used to loop through all the elements of the array)

```js
var values = "Artist - Title".split('-').map(i=>i.trim());
// creates : values = ["Artist","Title"]
var artist = values[0];
var title = values[1];

console.log(artist); // "Artist"
console.log(title);  // "Title"
```

If you want to avoid using `trim()`, you can split on `" - "` instead of just `"-"`

```js
 var values = "Artist - Title".split(' - ');
    // creates : values = ["Artist","Title"]
    var artist = values[0];
    var title = values[1];

    console.log(artist); // "Artist"
    console.log(title);  // "Title"
```